# Angular material table: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headerCell')

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am having problem with the header checkbox in Angular using material-table.

Whenever I add 4th column for checkbox, I am getting very strange error:   `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headerCell')`

Here you cann see my typescript file:

```js
export class VarViewNBtsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  columnsToDisplay: string[] = ['varSelect', 'varName', 'varType', 'varValue']; // here's 4 columns to display
  ddsVariablesLeft = new MatTableDataSource<DDSVariable>(); // DDSVariable has only three entries
  selection = new SelectionModel<DDSVariable>(true, []);

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ddsVariablesLeft.paginator = this.paginator;

    this.sharedService.getPathArrObs().subscribe((update) => {
      this.updTableData(update.data);
    });
  }
 }
```

and here's html template:

```html
<div class="left-table">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="ddsVariablesLeft">
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay; sticky:true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay" (click)="selection.toggle(row)"></tr>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="varSelect">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
                </mat-checkbox>
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
                </mat-checkbox>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- define column and its cells -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="varName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ddsVariable"> {{ddsVariable.name}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <!-- define column and its cells -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="varType">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Type </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ddsVariable"> {{ddsVariable.type}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <!-- define column and its cells -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="varValue">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ddsVariable"> {{ddsVariable.value}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr> -->

    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]=" [5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Also, whenever I click on this header, I get following errors:
[image]

Comment: `ViewChild`, `ngOnInit`, `undefined` error. Hm... What could be the problem? Try `{static: true}`.

Answer (score 0):

So, on another sunny day I've realized that in my html template, there're actually two tables. The second one were using the same columns to display array, but INSIDE there were only THREE columns to use.

Pretty stupid error :D